# Flash: Align locked objects

Tags: adobe-flash, alignment

So I am familiar with the align toolbar, and am attempting to get two objects to align centrally.

The problem is that one of the objects is where I want it to be placed, and I want the other object to centre itself against this object.

How would I go about keeping one element static and aligning another to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Flash go to :

**View > Snapping > Edit Snapping...**

And enable the last two checkboxes there from the **Center Alignment** options...

After you do this, when you move you object against your fixed object(you don't have to lock it or anything) some guides will appear, when the object is close to the center of the fixed object, or close to its edges...

have a look at the screenShots:

[image]

[image]

This is Flash CS 5.5 ... not sure when this option came along... so if you don't have it there... sorry :(

Hopes this helpes...

There are other workarounds for doing this... just ask if you need further help :)